# Javascript- How to reset button counter when timer reaches 0

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a simple click counter function to countdown the number of clicks users are left to use, where the number of clicks left will reset every 24 hours.
I've look through a few tutorials and implemented it visually in the alert once user has maxed the click. But how do I get about only resetting the count once the timer reaches 0.

HTML

```
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function clickCounter() {
    var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
          if(Number(localStorage.clickcount) <= 0){
    alert('You have max the number of connect \nTime left: '+ hours+':'+min+':'+sec);
            localStorage.clickcount =4;
        }
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)-1
        } 
      else
          {
            localStorage.clickcount = 4;
          } 
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.clickcount + " clicks left.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of how it's running. Currently I've set it to reset right after the alert pops out, and I'm just figuring how to reset automatically when the timer is up. Thanks for any feedback and help

[sample link](https://codepen.io/necrogaia/pen/bxbrbJ)

Comment: `if(hours === "00" && minutes === "00" && seconds === "00")` ...

Comment: Side note: be aware that you can reset the counter by using another browser, switching to incognito mode, by clearing browsing data in the browser settings, or even by typing some code in the browser console directly. Just in case you'd be using this code for something other than pure amusement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an interval function to check the time and reset values when time is up. I've changed your code to add a interval function

```
checkClickCount();

function clickCounter() {
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
    var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
    if ((min + '').length == 1) {
        min = '0' + min;
    }
    var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
    if ((sec + '').length == 1) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
    }

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            if (Number(localStorage.clickcount) < 1) {
                alert('You have max the number of connect \nTime left: ' + hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec);
                return;
            }
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) - 1
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 4;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.clickcount + " clicks left.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}

var intv = null;

function checkClickCount(){
  // interval run a function in a specified period of time
  intv = window.setInterval(function(){

    var currentTime = new Date();

    var remainDateTime = new Date();
    remainDateTime.setHours(24 - currentTime.getHours());
    remainDateTime.setMinutes(60 - currentTime.getMinutes());
    remainDateTime.setSeconds(60 - currentTime.getSeconds());



    if(localStorage.clickcount > 1){
      return;
    }

    // If the remaining times finished, the click count will be reset
    if(remainDateTime.getHours() + remainDateTime.getMinutes() + remainDateTime.getSeconds() == 0){
      localStorage.clickcount = 4;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have " + localStorage.clickcount + " clicks";
      return;
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You will get 4 more clicks in " + remainDateTime.getHours() + ":" + remainDateTime.getMinutes() + ":" + remainDateTime.getSeconds() + " later.";

  }, 1000);
}
```